# No module named 'flask_wtf' after trying to install flask-wtf with 'pip install flask-wtf'

Tags: python, pip, flask-wtforms

I'm trying install flask-wtf in my web app, but it can't be installed
from the terminal.

Error:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\PC\Desktop\code\Flask_Blog\forms.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\PC\Desktop\code\Flask_Blog\forms.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_wtf'
#when-i-install
Requirement already satisfied: flask-WTF in c:\users\pc\desktop\code\venv\lib\site-packages (0.14.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in c:\users\pc\desktop\code\venv\lib\site-packages (from flask-WTF) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: WTForms in c:\users\pc\desktop\code\venv\lib\site-packages (from flask-WTF) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in c:\users\pc\desktop\code\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-WTF) (0.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in c:\users\pc\desktop\code\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-WTF) (2.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in c:\users\pc\desktop\code\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-WTF) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in c:\users\pc\desktop\code\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-WTF) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\pc\desktop\code\venv\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->Flask->flask-WTF) (1.1.1)
```

Comment: Please write, what have you tried? Which command was run on terminal? Which error did it give?

Comment: Always check from which environment you run your code.
run 
`cd c:\users\pc\desktop\code`
then
`.\venv\Scripts\activate`
now you can run it.

Comment: thanks you so much.i found the problem

Comment: have beautiful day ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; Try to do the installation manually, it worked for me. First clone it with git:

```sh
git clone git://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf.git
```

Then all you have to do is run the `setup.py` file in it like this:

```sh
python setup.py install
```